# GitLab Account Pending approval from administrator

Tags: gitlab

Your account is pending approval from your GitLab administrator and hence blocked. Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is an error

Comment: What are you actually asking here?

Answer (score 1):

Well as the message states. You have created an account on a self-hosted GitLab instance.

The administrators of that instance have configured it so that they have to manually approve every account that is created. This is usually to prevent spam and exploiting of publicly reachable instance.

> When this setting is enabled, any user visiting your GitLab domain and signing up for a new account using the registration form must be explicitly approved by an administrator before they can start using their account. In GitLab 13.6 and later, this setting is enabled by default for new GitLab instances. It is only applicable if sign ups are enabled.
>
> *- gitlab docs; [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/sign_up_restrictions.html#require-administrator-approval-for-new-sign-ups)*

Answer (score 0):

The first time you access your self-hosted Gitlab it asks you to set up a password. Then you can access using user `root` and the password you set up. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem (Vbox, VM; self-managed gitlab on my VM's static IP).
I remembered installing with export GITLAB_HOME=/srv/gitlab
sudo more /srv/gitlab/initial_root_password
in that file is a long password which I used along with root as the user.